# How can I improve this code of elliptic curve factorization?

Tags: python-3.x, elliptic-curve, prime-factoring

First, I'm very noob :) I didn't studied deep on elliptic curves. I just google some elementary knowledge of prime factorization and elliptic curve.

I'm trying to make the python3 code implementation of elliptic curve factoring  algorithm. I just Followed the discription in [Lenstra's Elliptic Curve Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization), and with some functinons, class and implemented error, I managed to build the code:

```
from random import randint
from math import e as exp
from math import sqrt, log

class InvError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.value = v


def inv(a,n):
    r1, s1, t1 = 1, 0, a
    r2, s2, t2 = 0, 1, n
    while t2:
        q = t1//t2
        r1, r2 = r2, r1-q*r2
        s1, s2 = s2, s1-q*s2
        t1, t2 = t2, t1-q*t2

    if t1!=1: raise InvError(t1)
    else: return r1


class ECpoint(object):
    def __init__(self, A,B,N, x,y):
        if (y*y - x*x*x - A*x - B)%N != 0: raise ValueError
        self.A, self.B = A, B
        self.N = N
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def __add__(self, other):
        A,B,N = self.A, self.B, self.N
        Px, Py, Qx, Qy = self.x, self.y, other.x, other.y
        if Px == Qx and Py == Qy:
            s = (3*Px*Px + A)%N * inv((2*Py)%N, N) %N
        else:
            s = (Py-Qy)%N * inv((Px-Qx)%N, N) %N
        x = (s*s - Px - Qx) %N
        y = (s*(Px - x) - Py) %N
        return ECpoint(A,B,N, x,y)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        r = self; other -= 1
        while True:
            if other & 1:
                r = r + self
                if other==1: return r
            other >>= 1
            self = self+self


def ECM(n):
    x0 = 2
    y0 = 3
    bound = max(int(exp**(1/2*sqrt(log(n)*log(log(n))))),100)
    while True:
        try:
            a = randint(1,n-1)
            inv(a,n)
            b = (y0*y0 - x0*x0*x0 - a*x0) %n
            inv(b,n)
            inv((4*a*a*a + 27*b*b)%n, n)

            P = ECpoint(a,b,n, x0,y0)
            for k in range(2, bound):
                inv(P.x, n)
                inv(P.y, n)
                P = k*P
                #print(k,P)

        except InvError as e:
            d = e.value
            if d==n: continue
            else: return d, n//d


print(ECM(int(input())))
```

This code gets a composite number as input, and print two nontrivial divisors.

The code runs well for most of the inputs. Problem is, it's too slow...
I tested this code for some numbers between 60~120 bit integers(such as 2^101-1, 10^30-33, etc.), and what I encountered was it is even slower than roughly made Pollard's p-1 test like this:

```
def Pollard_pminus1(n):
    if '0' not in bin(n)[3:]: base = 3
    else: base = 2
    if n % base == 0: return base, n//base

    b = base; exp = 1
    while True:
        b = pow(b,exp,n)
        d = gcd(b-1,n)
        if d!=1: break
        exp += 1
    if d!=n: return d, n//d
```

And for inputs of roughly 50 digits(according to Wikipedia, this range should be the real playground for ECM...), this program is halted even for a day.

Can I improve the performance of this code? Is it worthy to optimize the boundary of the value k, or should I fix large part of this algorithm?

Thanks for your help, and sorry for poor language(if something wrong);;

Comment: Before you can optimize you need to know where the time is being spent. A quick look at your code *suggests* that you are not using the `inv` function sensibly. You only need to compute *one* inverse to add two points. That is the one place where you check if the inverse fails to exist and thus a factor is found. So get rid of all the lines like `inv(P.x, n)`.

Comment: I know there's no step of checking coprimeness of coordinates or other values in the original algorithm, but I inserted inv functions because maybe parameters a,b,P.x,P.y are not coprime to n, so by a luck, it raises error and yields to factorization. Is it that worthless?

Comment: It's not completely worthless, but it's no better than just guessing a factor and much more expensive.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for very interesting question!

I did some optimizations to your code, which improved its speed around **95x** times, after them factorization of 166 bit number (50 decimal digits, as you wished) takes from 10 minutes (see [11-minutes log](https://pastebin.com/raw/dwSiXTBR)) to 4 hours on my laptop (time varies depending on luck) and 132 bit (40 decimal digits) takes just 1 to 15 minutes. See final code at the very end of this post.

Following improvements were made:

1. Used [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module to occupy all CPU cores, instead of single-core version of your code. This change made your code 8 times faster on my 4-cores laptop (with 8 hardware threads).
2. Used [GMPY2](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to replace pure Python [int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) type with [gmpy2.mpz()](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mpz.html) type, which does all mathematics 2-3 times faster than Python due to highly optimized [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) library. Use of `gmpy2` module can be disabled (if you wish) by commenting line `import gmpy2`.
3. Replaced body of your pure Python `inv()` function with fast GMPY2-based [gmpy2.gcdext()](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mpz.html) implementation of [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). If `gmpy2` use is disabled in my code (which is possible) then built-in Python's [pow(a, -1, n)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) is used for inverting integer. `gmpy2.gcdext()` is faster than Python's `pow(a, -1, n)` and much faster than your `inv()` implementation of Extended Euclidean Algorithm. In Python's C source inverting a number through `pow(a, -1, n)` is done with similarly to yours Extended Euclidean Algorithm, source of which you can [see here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4fc68560ea0d506c152a82c48c162bfe002f34a8/Objects/longobject.c#L4074), this version is faster than yours due to only reason that it is totally C-based, of cause GMPY2's variant `gmpy2.gcdext()` is even more faster because it uses more mathemacially profound algorithms.
4. Replaced multiplication of curve point by `range(2, bound)` with multiplication just by all prime numbers within range `[2 ; bound]`. This is a significant improvement, because prime numbers are much more sparse than range of all numbers, hence much less multiplications. To make this change possible I had to introduce `bound_pow` constant such that `prime ** m <= bound_pow`, in other words I multiply not by prime itself but by its power within some bound. Power of prime is needed in a case when order of a curve has higher than 1 powers of some prime factors.
5. Removed unnecessary `inv(P.x, n)` and `inv(P.y, n)` which occupy significant time but don't do any useful work, because these two inversions have a not bigger chance of producing a factor than inverting any random number, so not useful at all.
6. Removed unnecessary check of elliptic curve invariant `(y ** 2 - x ** 3 - A * x - B) % N == 0` within body of ECpoint's constructor, because this check is done on every `__add__()` call and will fail only if point addition is implemented incorrectly, hence it is just a debug check which slows down things.
7. Did quite a lot of visualizations, printing to console of different values, timings and progress-meter.
8. Implemented functions for computation of many useful helper values, like optimal value of `bound` instead of your approximate formula (which I didn't use but just printed). Also computed optimal number of needed curves. Also function for calculating maximal factor size (with probability of miss `10%`) for the given bound and number of curves. Function for computing amount of work (`Work2()`) needed for given bound and number of curves.

Steps 1)-6) above are all doing speed improvements (steps 5)-6) are not very significant, only 1)-4) are important), you can reproduce them manually in your code, they are quite simple.

Example output for 112-bit composite (factored within 148 seconds):

```
Factoring 2524582745259710504267101693459139
Calculating. Wait...
n 2^110.96, bound 2^13.18 (optimal 2^14.24, 1.051x faster),
     need at most 974 curves (factor up to 2^55.48)
ooo
curves     1/974 (  0.103%),  factors < 2^14.508,  time  00:00:20
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
curves    86/974 (  8.830%),  factors < 2^41.646,  time  00:01:20
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
curves   179/974 ( 18.378%),  factors < 2^45.995,  time  00:02:21
oooooo
Factored on curve 190 (19.61%) (rand_seed = 248080385138786)!
ooo
Factors: P 38240987134592087, P 66017719060814197
2 prime, 0 composite
All factors are prime!!!
Time 148.2 sec
```

Example for 166 bit number (50 digit), with `random.seed(1)`, takes 11.5 minutes to factor:

```
Factoring 45733304697523851846830687775886905451041736136239
Calculating. Wait...
n 2^164.97, bound 2^16.79 (optimal 2^17.43, 1.023x faster), need at most 5722 curves (factor up to 2^82.48)
........................................o
curves     1/5722 (  0.017%),  factors < 2^18.480,  time  00:00:25
ooooooo........................................oooooooo........................................oooooooo........................................o
curves    25/5722 (  0.437%),  factors < 2^43.197,  time  00:01:25
ooooooo........................................oooooooo........................................oooooooo......................................o
curves    49/5722 (  0.856%),  factors < 2^48.646,  time  00:02:26
..ooooooo....................................o....ooooooo....................................o....ooooooo....................................o
curves    73/5722 (  1.276%),  factors < 2^51.779,  time  00:03:27
...o.oooooo..................................o.....o.oooooo..................................o....o.o.ooooo..................................o
curves    97/5722 (  1.695%),  factors < 2^53.972,  time  00:04:28
....o.oo.oooo..................................o....o.oooo.oo..................................o....o.ooo.ooo..................................o
curves   121/5722 (  2.115%),  factors < 2^55.655,  time  00:05:29
.....oooo.ooo..................................o....o.ooo.oo.o.................................o....o.ooo.oo.o.................................o
curves   145/5722 (  2.534%),  factors < 2^57.017,  time  00:06:29
....o.oooo.o.o.................................o....o.ooo.oo.o.................................o...o..oooo.o.o.................................o
curves   169/5722 (  2.954%),  factors < 2^58.161,  time  00:07:30
o.....oooo.o.o.................................oo.....oooo.o.o.................................oo.....oo.ooo.o.................................o
curves   193/5722 (  3.373%),  factors < 2^59.145,  time  00:08:31
o.....oo.ooo.o.................................oo.....oo.ooo.o.................................oo.....oooo..oo................................o
curves   217/5722 (  3.792%),  factors < 2^60.009,  time  00:09:31
.o.....oooo..oo.................................oo.....oooo..o.o................................oo.....oooo..o.o...............................o
curves   241/5722 (  4.212%),  factors < 2^60.778,  time  00:10:32
.o.....oooo..o.o...............................o.o.....oooo..o.o...............................o.o.....oooo..o.o...............................o
curves   265/5722 (  4.631%),  factors < 2^61.470,  time  00:11:33
.o.....oooo..o.o...............................o.o....o.ooo..o.o............
Factored on curve 282 (4.95%) (rand_seed = 83739500771956)!

Factors: P 4856082635476451488745861, P 9417736091106851081336099
2 prime, 0 composite
All factors are prime!!!
Time 724.9 sec
```

For demo purposes in my `test()` function I compose a composite number as a product of two prime numbers equal in bit-length (same as in RSA). Bit length of composite number is given by `bits` constant.

All randomness in my code is deterministic due to usage of `random.seed(0)` in the beginning of script. This seed is set fixed so that you can reproduce exactly same deterministic results within several runs of script. You may change this seed value if you wish to have other randomness and hence other generated composite and curves. As you can see in example console output above, at the end I show `rand_seed` value for the successful curve that factored a number, this seed value is useful if you want to reproduce once again exact params of a curve for fast redoing of factoring, or to give this successful curve to your friends.

Number of curves needed is computed such that you have exactly just `10%` of chance to miss a factor if a factor has bit length equal to half of composite's bit length. In other words in worst case, when a factor is largest possible, then if you run all these number of curves then you have exactly `10%` chance of missing such factor (`90%` chance of successful factorization). If you run twice more curves then you'll get just `1%` chance of miss (`99%` chance of success). If you want to get `50%` chance of factoring then you have to check just `1/3`-th of computed amount of curves. Many times I got successful factorization just after checking `1/10`-th of needed amount of curves, in this case chance of hitting a factor is `10%` (`90%` miss chance).

Usage of GMPY2 library gives around `1.8x` times overall speedup compared to pure Python integers, so very significant, almost two times faster. If you want pure Python solution then just comment out `import gmpy2` in first lines of script. On Linux you can install gmpy2 through `sudo apt install python3-gmpy2`. On Windows download wheels file [from here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gmpy) for corresponding Python version and install it through e.g. `python -m pip install gmpy2‑2.0.8‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl`.

Further `20%` speedup can be achieved if you compute [Non-Adjacent Form, wNAF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#w-ary_non-adjacent_form_(wNAF)_method), this method reduces greatly amount of needed additions (from `50%` for random distribution of 1-bits to `10%`), amount of doublings (adding same point to same point) remain the same. I did this method in my `ECM` library (other script) and it gave me `20%` overall speedup. Also to use this method you have to precompute product (multiply) around `200` prime numbers in a row, unlike current method where you can multiply just one by one prime number.

You can see that I precomputed and printed to console `optimal` bound, computed using `OptimalBoundLog()` function, using this bound should give around `3-5%` more speedup, although I didn't use this bound in my code below.

**Note**. I also implemented my own elliptic curve factorization script in Python, this script is considerably longer and it has point multiplication implemented in pure C++ (with Cython wrapper). I did timings of Python-only (GMPY2-based) multiplication and C++ version, they differ `3x` times. So C++ gives extra `3x` times boost.

If to approximately calculate total speedup, then we'll have: `8x` due to multiprocessing (I have 8 cores at home), `1.8x` due to use of GMPY2, `2x` due to use of `gmpy2.gcdext()` instead of Pythonic version of Extended Euclidean Algorithm, around `3x` due to use of prime numbers instead of consecutive numbers, `1.1x` due to removing all unnecessary code like `inv(P.x, n)`, `3x` due to use of C++ for point multiplication (which I used only in my library, not posted here), also `1.2x` boost can be gained if to implement [Non-Adjacent Form (wNAF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#w-ary_non-adjacent_form_(wNAF)_method). Total of **340x** times speedup!

Also you should take into account that actual running time depends greatly on your luck. Sometimes you should check just `3%` (if you're very luck) of all computed amount of needed curves before you find a factor, sometimes you have to check `200%` of them (if you're very unlucky). Checking `100%` of them will give a probability of `90%` to find a factor (or `10%` probability to miss a factor). Of course time also depends on bit length of a smallest factor. This amount of needed curves was computed for the worst case, when factor has bit length equal to half of bit length of input composite number `n`.

You can see at the very end of successful factoring that I show something similar to `Factored on curve 190 (19.61%) (rand_seed = 248080385138786)!`, here `rand_seed` is very significant, it uniquely identifies last curve that successfully factored the number. If you have long running factorization then at the end you should remember this seed value so that you can immediately reproduce results of factoring. To reproduce results just input same composite number to your `ECM()` function, and replace `'rand_seed': random.randrange(1 << 48),` in code with `'rand_seed': 248080385138786,` (this seed value is taken from example output above). And rerun the script, then you should see successful factoring result at the very beginning at 0-th curve. Very **important** - do this modification of `rand_seed` in the script only temporarily, revert it back to `'rand_seed': random.randrange(1 << 48),` after you're done, otherwise you'll destroy all source of randomness for other input `n` numbers, which will result in infinite unsuccsessful factorization runs. You can also make this `rand_seed` as an optional argument to `ECM()` function so that you don't need to modify code inplace.

To play with following code try to modify two values - bit length of input composite number, it is set through `bits` variable at the end of script inside `test()` function (right now it is `112` bits). Second - try modifying line `random.seed(0)` at the very beginning of a script, change seed value to other values like `1`, `2`, `3` etc. If you don't change this seed then you'll get exactly same results of running a script every time. This seed controls behaviour of all random values inside script. Same seed is needed if you want to reproduce exactly same results of script runs for some reason, like showing results to your friends.

Improved code itself:

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow54176869#main.py)

```py
gmpy2 = None
import gmpy2

import random
random.seed(0)

class InvError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.value = v

def Int(x):
    return int(x) if gmpy2 is None else gmpy2.mpz(x)

def inv(a, n):
    a %= n
    if gmpy2 is None:
        try:
            return pow(a, -1, n)
        except ValueError:
            import math
            raise InvError(math.gcd(a, n))
    else:
        g, s, t = gmpy2.gcdext(a, n)
        if g != 1:
            raise InvError(g)
        return s % n
    
    # Slow version below
    '''
    r1, s1, t1 = 1, 0, a
    r2, s2, t2 = 0, 1, n
    while t2:
        q = t1//t2
        r1, r2 = r2, r1-q*r2
        s1, s2 = s2, s1-q*s2
        t1, t2 = t2, t1-q*t2

    if t1!=1: raise InvError(t1)
    else: return r1
    '''


class ECpoint(object):
    def __init__(self, A, B, N, x, y, *, prepare = True):
        if prepare:
            N = Int(N)
            A, B, x, y = [Int(e) % N for e in [A, B, x, y]]
            if (y ** 2 - x ** 3 - A * x - B) % N != 0:
                raise ValueError
        self.A, self.B, self.N, self.x, self.y = A, B, N, x, y
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        A, B, N = self.A, self.B, self.N
        Px, Py, Qx, Qy = self.x, self.y, other.x, other.y
        if Px == Qx and Py == Qy:
            s = ((Px * Px * 3 + A) * inv(Py * 2, N)) % N
        else:
            s = ((Py - Qy) * inv(Px - Qx, N)) % N
        x = (s * s - Px - Qx) % N
        y = (s * (Px - x) - Py) % N
        return ECpoint(A, B, N, x, y, prepare = False)
    
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        other = Int(other - 1)
        r = self
        while True:
            if other & 1:
                r = r + self
                if other == 1:
                    return r
            other >>= 1
            self = self + self
    
def BinarySearch(f, a, b):
    while a < b:
        m = (a + b) // 2
        if f(m):
            b = m
        else:
            a = m + 1
    assert a == b and f(a), (a, b, f(a))
    return a

def FactorBitSize(bound, ncurves, miss_prob = 0.1):
    import math
    bound_log2 = math.log2(bound)
    def Prob(factor_log2):
        x = factor_log2 / bound_log2
        return x ** -x
    def F(factor_log2):
        return (1. - Prob(factor_log2)) ** ncurves >= miss_prob
    return BinarySearch(lambda x: F(x / 1000.), math.log2(bound) * 1000., 512 * 1000.) / 1000.

def NeededCurves(bound, target_fac_log2, miss_prob = 0.1):
    def F(ncurves):
        return FactorBitSize(bound, ncurves, miss_prob) >= target_fac_log2
    return round(BinarySearch(lambda x: F(x), 1, 10 ** 15))

def Work(bound, bound_pow, *, logs = [0.], cache = {}):
    if bound not in cache:
        import math
        for ilog in range(100):
            if get_prime(1 << ilog) >= bound:
                break
        cnt_primes = BinarySearch(lambda i: get_prime(i) >= bound, 0, 1 << ilog)
        bound_pow = max(bound, bound_pow)
        bound_log = math.log2(bound)
        bound_pow_log = math.log2(bound_pow)
        while cnt_primes >= len(logs):
            plog = math.log2(get_prime(len(logs)))
            sum_plog = plog
            while True:
                sum_plog += plog
                if sum_plog >= max(bound_log, bound_pow_log):
                    sum_plog -= plog
                    break
            logs.append(logs[-1] + sum_plog)
        cache[bound] = logs[cnt_primes]
    return cache[bound]

def Work2(bound, bound_pow, factor_log):
    return Work(bound, bound_pow) * NeededCurves(bound, factor_log)

def OptimalBoundLog(factor_log, bound_pow):
    import math
    mwork = None
    bound_log_start = 10
    for bound_log in range(bound_log_start, math.floor(factor_log) + 1):
        bound = 2 ** bound_log
        work = Work(bound, bound_pow) * NeededCurves(bound, factor_log)
        if mwork is not None and work > mwork[0]:
            break
        if mwork is None or work < mwork[0]:
            mwork = (work, bound_log)
    else:
        bound_log = bound_log_start + 1
    mult = 200
    mwork = None
    for bound_log2 in range((bound_log - 3) * mult, bound_log * mult + 1):
        bound = round(2 ** (bound_log2 / mult))
        work = Work(bound, bound_pow) * NeededCurves(bound, factor_log)
        if mwork is None or work < mwork[0]:
            mwork = (work, bound_log2 / mult)
    return mwork[1]

def get_prime(i, *, primes = [2, 3]):
    while i >= len(primes):
        for n in range(primes[-1] + 2, 1 << 62, 2):
            isp = True
            for p in primes:
                if p * p > n:
                    break
                if n % p == 0:
                    isp = False
                    break
            if isp:
                primes.append(n)
                break
    return primes[i]

def prime_power(idx, bound, bound_pow, *, cache = {}):
    key = (bound, bound_pow)
    if key not in cache:
        bound_pow = max(bound, bound_pow)
        r = []
        for i in range(1 << 62):
            p = get_prime(i)
            if p >= bound:
                break
            m = p
            while True:
                m2 = m * p
                if m2 >= bound_pow:
                    break
                m = m2
            r.append(m)
        cache[key] = r
    return cache[key][idx] if idx < len(cache[key]) else None

def ExcInfo(ex):
    return f'{type(ex).__name__}: {ex}'

def ProcessCurve(*, n, bound, bound_pow, shared, rand_seed, curve_idx, num_curves):
    try:
        random.seed(rand_seed)
        x0, y0, a = [random.randrange(1, n) for i in range(3)]
        # x0 = 2; y0 = 3
        b = (y0 ** 2 - x0 ** 3 - a * x0) % n
        
        P = ECpoint(a,b,n, x0,y0)
        for i in range(1 << 62):
            if shared.get('finish', False):
                return {'ex': 'Interrupted: Finishing...'}
            k = prime_power(i, bound, bound_pow)
            if i > 0 and i % 2000 == 0 or k is None:
                Print(('.', 'o')[k is None], end = '', flush = True)
            if k is None:
                break
            P = k * P
    except InvError as e:
        d = e.value
        if d != n:
            Print(f'\nFactored on curve {curve_idx} ({(curve_idx + 1) / num_curves * 100.:.02f}%) (rand_seed = {rand_seed})!')
            return {'factors': sorted([d, n // d])}
    except BaseException as ex:
        shared['finish'] = True
        return {'ex': ExcInfo(ex)}
    return {}

def Print(*pargs, **nargs):
    print(*pargs, **{'flush': True, **nargs})

def ECM(n, *, processes = None):
    import math, multiprocessing as mp, time
    from datetime import datetime as dt
    
    Print(f'Factoring {n}')
    
    if fermat_prp(n):
        return [n]
    
    Print('Calculating. Wait...')
    
    start_time = dt.now()
    bound = max(int(math.e**(1/2*math.sqrt(math.log(n)*math.log(math.log(n))))),100)
    bound_pow = max(bound, 1 << 18)
    factor_log = math.log2(n) / 2
    max_curves = NeededCurves(bound, factor_log)
    opt_bound_log = OptimalBoundLog(factor_log, bound_pow)
    processes = processes or mp.cpu_count()
    
    Print(f'n 2^{math.log2(n):.02f}, bound 2^{math.log2(bound):.02f} (optimal 2^{opt_bound_log:.02f}, ' +
        f'{Work2(bound, bound_pow, factor_log) / Work2(2 ** opt_bound_log, bound_pow, factor_log):.03f}x faster), ' +
        f'need at most {max_curves} curves (factor up to 2^{factor_log:.02f})')
    
    with mp.Manager() as manager, mp.Pool(processes) as pool:
        try:
            ncurves, report_time = 0, 0
            shared = manager.dict()
            res = []
            for icurve in range(1 << 62):
                res.append(pool.apply_async(ProcessCurve, (),
                    {
                        'n': n, 'bound': bound, 'bound_pow': bound_pow,
                        'shared': shared, 'rand_seed': random.randrange(1 << 48),
                        'curve_idx': icurve, 'num_curves': max_curves,
                    }))
                if len(res) < processes * 9:
                    continue
                while len(res) >= processes * 6:
                    res2 = []
                    for e in res:
                        if not e.ready():
                            res2.append(e)
                            continue
                        e = e.get()
                        assert 'ex' not in e, e['ex']
                        if 'factors' in e:
                            return e['factors']
                        ncurves += 1
                        if time.time() - report_time >= 60:
                            Print(f'\ncurves {ncurves:>5}/{max_curves} ({ncurves / max_curves * 100.:>7.03f}%),  factors ' +
                                f'< 2^{FactorBitSize(bound, ncurves):.03f},  ' +
                                f'time {(dt(2000, 1, 1) + (dt.now() - start_time)).strftime("%H:%M:%S"):>9}')
                            report_time = time.time()
                    res = res2
                    time.sleep(0.01)
        except BaseException as ex:
            Print(f'\nException: {ExcInfo(ex)}. Finishing, wait!')
        finally:
            shared['finish'] = True
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
            Print()
    
    return [n]

def fermat_prp(n, trials = 32):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test
    if n <= 16:
        return n in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13)
    for i in range(trials):
        if pow(random.randint(2, n - 2), n - 1, n) != 1:
            return False
    return True

def gen_random_prime(bits):
    while True:
        n = random.randrange(1 << (bits - 1), 1 << bits)
        if fermat_prp(n):
            return n

def Prod(it):
    import functools
    return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, it, 1)
    
def test():
    import time
    # First 190 digits of Pi
    pi = 1415926535_8979323846_2643383279_5028841971_6939937510_5820974944_5923078164_0628620899_8628034825_3421170679_8214808651_3282306647_0938446095_5058223172_5359408128_4811174502_8410270193_8521105559_6446229489
    bits = 112
    nprimes = 2
    n = Prod([gen_random_prime(bits // nprimes) for i in range(nprimes)])
    tb = time.time()
    fs = ECM(n)
    Print('Factors:', ', '.join([('C', 'P')[fermat_prp(e)] + f' {e}' for e in fs]))
    assert n == Prod(fs), (n, fs)
    Print(sum(fermat_prp(e) for e in fs), 'prime,', sum(not fermat_prp(e) for e in fs), 'composite')
    Print('All factors are prime!!!' if all(fermat_prp(e) for e in fs) else 'Composite factors remaining...')
    Print(f'Time {time.time() - tb:.01f} sec')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```